# Assert an integer is within range

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, python-unittest

I am writing some unittests in python that are testing if I receive an integer. However sometimes this integer can be off by 1 or 2 and I don't really care. Essentially I want to be able to assert that the received integer is within a certain range, something like:

```
self.assertBetween(998, 1000, my_integer)
```

Is there an accepted way of doing this? Or will I have to do something like this:

```
self.assertTrue(998 <= my_integer)
self.assertTrue(my_integer <= 1000)
```

**EDIT**
The answers so far suggest:

```
self.assertTrue(998 <= my_integer <= 1000)
```

Is there any benefit of this over my example with 2 asserts?

Comment: Whether you use 1 or 2 asserts depends on what you really want to know and communicate.  If you only care that `my_integer` is between the limits, one assert is a cleaner more concise means to test and communicate that to the next guy looking at the code (which maybe you in 3 months).  If instead there is a good reason to know if `my_integer` is below 1000 separately to also knowing if `my_integer` is above 998, then it makes more sense to use 2 asserts.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use a "[chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)":

```
self.assertTrue(998 <= my_integer <= 1000)
```

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me: you asked if there's any benefit to this over your two separate conditionals.  Yes.  It's more concise, clearer, and more efficient (one function call instead of two).

Comment: @JohnZwinck while I agree this is shorter, I do not think this is something I would recommend because it has the same drawback as two `assertTrue`s. You lose verbosity of FAIL-message. With `assertTrue`, you'll get `AssertionError: False is not true`, which is not very helpful. I prefer to see what's wrong, so I would rather use `assertGreaterEqual(my_integer, 998); assertLessEqual(my_integer, 1000)` - that way you'll know what's wrong immediately (e.g.: `AssertionError: 100 not greater or equal to 998`).

Comment: the error message with this assertion wouldn't tell what was the value of `my_integer` or the limits (usually you don't have hard-coded limits like these). so I'd prefer the assertBetween method in @JanSpurny's answer.

Answer (score 29):

Python has a [built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertAlmostEqual) you may use for this: `assertAlmostEqual`.

```
self.assertAlmostEqual(myinteger, 999, delta=1)
# is equivalent to
self.assertTrue(998 <= myinteger <= 1000)
# ... but gives better error messages.
```

The optional parameter delta specifies the allowed distance from the value you're testing.

Answer (score 18):

I don't think it's a good idea to use `assertTrue` with comparison inside -
that way you lose any information in FAIL message:

```
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Which is not helpful at all and you're basicaly back to "raw" `assert` and you are losing a lot of `unittest`'s methods benefits.

I would recommend either:

## Creating your own custom assert

in which you can print more meaningful message. For example:

```
import unittest

class BetweenAssertMixin(object):
    def assertBetween(self, x, lo, hi):
        if not (lo <= x <= hi):
            raise AssertionError('%r not between %r and %r' % (x, lo, hi))

class Test1(unittest.TestCase, BetweenAssertMixin):
    def test_between(self):
        self.assertBetween(999, 998, 1000)

    def test_too_low(self):
        self.assertBetween(997, 998, 1000)

    def test_too_high(self):
        self.assertBetween(1001, 998, 1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

then you'll have following output (shortened):

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_too_high (__main__.Test1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 19, in test_too_high
    self.assertBetween(1001, 998, 1000)
  File "example.py", line 8, in assertBetween
    raise AssertionError('%r is not between %r and %r' % (x, lo, hi))
AssertionError: 1001 is not between 998 and 1000
======================================================================
FAIL: test_too_low (__main__.Test1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 16, in test_too_low
    self.assertBetween(997, 998, 1000)
  File "example.py", line 8, in assertBetween
    raise AssertionError('%r is not between %r and %r' % (x, lo, hi))
AssertionError: 997 is not between 998 and 1000
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Or use `assertLessEqual` and `assertGreaterEqual`

if you don't want custom assert (which does add another traceback record and several lines of code):

```
...
def test_no_custom_assert(self):
    my_integer = 100
    self.assertGreaterEqual(my_integer, 998)
    self.assertLessEqual(my_integer, 1000)
...
```

which is a bit longer (it may be shorter in total than adding custom assert if it's used only once) than `assertTrue(998 <= my_integer <= 1000)` but you'll still get nice fail messages (also without additional traceback record):

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_no_custom_assert (__main__.Test1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 23, in test_no_custom_assert
    self.assertGreaterEqual(my_integer, 998)
AssertionError: 100 not greater than or equal to 998
```

Comment: If you put your custom assertion method in a module with a `_unittest` global the traceback will be omitted, and you'll get the nice clean traceback of using a builtin `TestCase.assertX` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
self.assertTrue(998 <= my_integer <= 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be the following class, which comes in very handy if you want to compare numbers in a `dict` easily:

```py
@dataclass
class IsBetweenOrEqual:
    lower_bound: float
    upper_bound: float

    def __eq__(self, actual) -> bool:
        return self.lower_bound <= actual <= self.upper_bound
```

The class in action:

```py
3 == IsBetweenOrEqual(2, 3)
>>> True
3 == IsBetweenOrEqual(2, 2.5)
>>> False
```

Comparing numbers in a dict:

```
allowed_dict = {"num1": IsBetweenOrEqual(0, 2), "num2": 2}
test_dict1 = {"num1": 1, "num2": 2}
test_dict2 = {"num1": 10, "num2": 2}

test_dict1 == allowed_dict
>>> True
test_dict2 == allowed_dict
>>> False
```